# How to track the lifecycle of Kafka messages flowing from multiple topics?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a scenario where there are multiple components, multiple topics where messages are produced, processed and consumed. Finally there is a single component, who is consuming the messages from multiple topics. How can we track the lifecycle of the messages with timestamp, i.e. the birth of the messages, the end (which components these messages have travelled through).

Does Kafka has its build in mechanism where we could track with the unique id, timestamp or something else? Of we need to write the logic in every specific components and send out the unique ids and timestamp in the payload. Alongside the challenge is the payload/messages could be different from multiple components therefore the final component should be generic consuming different formats.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not have anything like this built-in.

You can easily introduce [distributed tracing](https://www.confluent.io/blog/importance-of-distributed-tracing-for-apache-kafka-based-applications/) into clients, however, which, yes, requires you to introduce tracing spans into individual components

[image]

Comment: are there any examples on introducing tracing spans. I am using Kafka Cloud Stream. Are these traces introduced as Kafka headers?

Comment: Spring Cloud Sleuth includes the Kafka Brave interceptor integration

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.